# ubuntu 15.10 - shrinking volumes and removing others

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

[image]

I have the above volumes. Basicly it's an ubuntu 15.10 dual boot with windows 10.
I want to shrink all the volumes in order to make them fit inside a 250GB SSD(Now I have HDD). I can't manage to shrink the /dev/sda4 and /dev/sda6 volumes because when I try to resize them I can't shrink the new size.

Comment: Which do you want to remove ? You can mess your dual boot

Comment: I don't want to remove, I just want to shrink sda4 and sda6

Answer (score 0):

You have to launch gparted from live http://gparted.org/download.php
You can't move these volumes because they are mounted. Make backups before this operation